# Loading angularjs dynamically and generating controllers and scope

Tags: javascript, dynamic, angularjs, dom-manipulation

I want to use angular in an app except that angular is not loaded by default with the app. When a particular button is clicked, a new div is created and I want to use angular on that div.

I'm loading angular using yepnode as shown in the code below:

```
yepnope({
    test:window.angular,nope: ['/filesystem/content/js/angular.js'],
    complete: function(){ console.log('complete');}
});
```

Given that I've loaded angular and I have access to the div as $div, my next action will be

```
1. Create some html and use it as the innerHTML of $div
2. Create a controller (from another file eg /filesystem/controllers/abc.js
3. bind $div to controller and scope.
```

Not really sure how to proceed since in all my examples, I started with a page with angular loaded at started together with putting the ng-app tag on the html.

After loading angularjs, what are the next steps?

Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap shows you how to do manual bootstrap.

Comment: @toshshimayama: Exactly what I needed. Was able to bootstrap $div. Now looking at the controller. Can you post your comment as an answer so I accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angularjs guide page would help you.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

There is a description how to do the manual bootstrapping.